# Eclipse freeze on opening declaration in long file

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT on linux. I have a long header file with 5k lines of code. When I try to open declaration of some variable in this file by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>, Eclipse freezes for about 20 seconds and then opens declaration. This issue makes code navigation unusable in a long file. In shorter files declaration opens almost instantly.

I tried to restart Eclipse and rebuild the index but this did not help.
My Eclipse version is:

```
Version: Neon.1 (4.6.1)
Build id: Z20161111-1340
```

How can I workaround this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is [Eclipse bug 455467](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455467).

The reason of freeze is high cpu usage when opening declaration.
I applied workaround from [Comment 5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455467#c5) and freeze dropped to 1-5 seconds:

> Changing all settings in
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.prefs
>   from RUN_AS_YOU_TYPE\=>true to RUN_AS_YOU_TYPE\=>false seems to help
>   us out of this but this is not really what we want.

As I understand this workaround partially disables Codan - CDT static analysis framework.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way CDT is architected, operations on larger files will be slower than operations on smaller files.

CDT obtains semantic information about the code for operations like Open Declaration from two places:

- For the currently open file: from the **AST** (abstract syntax tree) it builds for that file.
- For included header files and other files in the project: from the **index**, which is a searchable database of semantic information about the project.

The index is initially built by creating an AST for every file in the project, and storing information from them into a database. This is a time-consuming process, but it only has to be done once (and then it's incrementally updated every time you save a file), and once it's built, querying the index is fast (querying is about **O(log n)** in the size of the index).

On the other hand, since the AST represents code that is (potentially) being currently edited, it is constantly being rebuilt "as you type". Since building an AST is at least **O(n)** in the length of the file (possibly worse; I haven't done a careful analysis), operations that depend on the AST get slower as the length of the file you're editing increases.

Now, for workarounds:

1. Enabling some of the **scalability settings** in `Preferences | C/C++ | Editor | Scalability` may help, by restricting the kinds of operations that require building an AST for large files (notice you get to define the threshold for "large"). It's not immediately clear to me whether it will make Open Declaration faster; try it and see.
2. Your best bet, however, is to **break your header up into smaller headers**. This has the added advantage of reducing compile times (since not all translation units may need to include all parts of the header), and organizing your code better (this last one is a matter of taste; feel free to disagree).